# Same Content for all TabItems in TabControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I want to show the same content for all `TabItem`s in a `TabControl`:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
        <StackPanel>
            <ComboBox />
            <Button Content="Button" x:Name="bButton" />
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 2" />
    <TabItem Header="Tab 3" />
</TabControl>
```

Is there an easy way to do this without repeating the code and only in XAML (not using code-behind)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I moved the `<StackPanel>` outside the `<TabControl>` and set the margins to place it on top of the TabControl:

```
<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TabItem Header="Tab 1" />
    <TabItem Header="Tab 2" />
    <TabItem Header="Tab 3" />
</TabControl>
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,50,0,0">
    <ComboBox />
    <Button Content="Button" x:Name="bButton" />
</StackPanel>
```

This is the cleanest and simplest approach.

Comment: This is not "Same Content for all TabItems in TabControl" as the title suggests.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it like this. Define the common resource in xaml.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel x:Key="CommonTabContent">
        <ComboBox />
        <Button Content="Button" x:Name="bButton" Click="bButton_Click_1" />
    </StackPanel>

</Window.Resources>
```

and use it like

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 1" Content="{StaticResource CommonTabContent}"/>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 2" Content="{StaticResource CommonTabContent}" />
    <TabItem Header="Tab 3" Content="{StaticResource CommonTabContent}" />
</TabControl>
```

Your .cs file code will contain the method.

```
private void bButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // your code
}
```

hope it helps..

Comment: but why you need to access a button?

Comment: you can bind a command with button. you dont need click event handling.

Comment: I just checked, you cannot access bButton but you can still bind an event. I have updated the code for you.

Comment: What if I want to access a comboboxes events and properties?

Comment: you need to understand the concept of wpf binding and how the context based programming is done. you can find mvvm + wpf articles in google and understand it.

Comment: Can you show me an example to access the SelectedIndex property of a combobox?

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer. Simple, clean, and flexible. +1.

Answer (score 2):

You could:

1. Extract the content into a `UserControl` and use it in each `TabItem`
2. Create a `ControlTemplate` and apply it to an instance of `Control` in each `TabItem`
3. Define a `DataTemplate` and use the `ItemsSource` of `TabControl` to apply the template to each child

The first approach is probably the sanest, especially if you need to access the contents of each tab page separately.